# Not seeing set_address packet using USBTrace

Tags: pic, usb, analysis, protocol, setup

I'm currently exploring the wonderous world of the USB Stack. I'm using a PIC18F2550 and the USB IO example available at [www.moty22.co.uk](http://www.moty22.co.uk/usbio.php). The code works as expected, but when using USBTrace (or any other USB sniffer) I fail to see the set_address setup packet. I see it ask for each descriptor and receive them, but nowhere in the log do I see a setup packet to set the address.

I fail to see this packet even when using other usb devices like my mouse, keyboard, and flash drives. Which got me to thinking if I would even be able to see these packets using USBTrace? Or would I need to be using an oscilloscope and debugging at the bus level?

I can post log output from USBTrace if neccessary, but I don't think it'll help much.

Comment: Not sure how much help this will be, but using Wireshark to monitor my laptop's USB ports, I initially didn't see any set_address packets either.  However, after I unplugged my mouse's USB wireless receiver and then plugging it back in, there was a Host-to-device SET ADDRESS Request.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I did (unplugging the device and plugging it back in) when testing. I haven't tried wireshark, so perhaps I'll give that a go when I get an oppertunity.

Comment: I've not used USBTrace.  Perhaps it requires special configuration or maybe a bug report submitted?

Comment: For me, Fedora 19, Wireshark "just worked".  If it doesn't "just work" for you, the [Wireshark USB Capture Setup Wiki Page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) may help.

Comment: Ah you're on Fedora, I'm using windows, so perhaps that's been my problem all along! I'm still not seeing it through windows, so I guess it's off to a live distro